# ASP.NET User management templates

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I've built a few ASP.NET sites that all use Users/Roles membership providers. These are working great, however for advanced user management tasks i have to go into the VS IDE and open the "Web Site Administration tool"

My question is, does anyone know of a template or set of prebuilt aspx pages out there that i can publish to a secure folder on my ASP.NET that allows me to manage all users from in that site.

I need the basic functions such as 
- Add new users
- Reset Passwords
- Unlock Accounts
- Delete users

I know how to build this functionality myself but i was hoping it's already out there so i can save some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a link on Scott Guthrie's blog, but it seemed to be down. However, [this blog](http://blog.geeksgonebad.com/2009/03/24/aspnet-remote-membership-tool/) has a link to it. Not sure how up to date it is, but you could try and see if it works. Another option is to use the Membership Manager from [here](http://www.qualitydata.com/default.aspx). There's a free trial available.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I might be needing something similar soon, so it's nice to know that the product is good.